# Parsing an XML file and creating an object with multiple properties from the XML

Tags: c#, xml

This question contains some C# code I've written as well as a XML format I have designed. My C# code runs a series of "jobs" by loading the XML file and then calling different SQL stored procedures and E-Mailing the results to different addresses. My question specifically relates to the C# code to parse the XML document and also how well designed the XML format is.

The code allows for a variable number of email addresses and stored procedure parameters. To allow for multiple named stored procedure parameters, I'm using a dictionary. The key is the name of the parameter and the value is the value to be used with said parameter.

**My questions:**

- How well designed is the XML?
- How good or bad is the C# code to parse the file?

  - How can it be improved?
  - Is there anything majorly wrong with it?

This is the XML format I'm using (in this case there are only two jobs defined):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<jobService>

  <job name="Report" storedProcedure="Procedure">
    <procedureParameter name="anotherStoredProcedureParameter1" value="test" />
    <procedureParameter name="anotherStoredProcedureParameter2" value="123456789" />

    <emailSettings subjectName="Subject" attachmentName="SomeFileName1.csv" senderAddress="address@address.com">
      <recipients>
        <address value="address@address.com />
        <address value="address@address.com />
      </recipients>

      <recipientsBcc>
        <address value="address@address.com />
        <address value="address@address.com />
      </recipientsBcc>

      <recipientsCC>
        <address value="address@address.com />
        <address value="address@address.com />
      </recipientsCC>
    </emailSettings>
  </job>

  <job name="Report #2" storedProcedure="Procedure2">
    <procedureParameter name="anotherStoredProcedureParameter1" value="test" />
    <procedureParameter name="anotherStoredProcedureParameter2" value="test" />
    <procedureParameter name="anotherStoredProcedureParameter3" value="test" />
    <procedureParameter name="anotherStoredProcedureParameter4" value="test" />

    <emailSettings subjectName="Subject" attachmentName="SomeFileName1.csv" senderAddress="address@address.com">
      <recipients>
        <address value="address@address.com />
        <address value="address@address.com />
      </recipients>

      <recipientsBcc>
        <address value="address@address.com />
        <address value="address@address.com />
      </recipientsBcc>

      <recipientsCC>
        <address value="address@address.com />
        <address value="address@address.com />
      </recipientsCC>
    </emailSettings>
  </job>
</jobService>
```

And this is the C# code to parse the XML:

```
public IEnumerable<JobConfiguration> GetJobConfigurations()
{
    XDocument jobs = XDocument.Load(@"jobs.xml");

    var query = jobs.Descendants("jobService").Descendants("job")
        .Select(x => new JobConfiguration
        {
            Name = x.Attribute("name").Value,
            StoredProcedure = x.Attribute("storedProcedure").Value,
            ProcedureParameters = x.Elements("procedureParameter").ToDictionary(p => p.Attribute("name").Value, p => p.Attribute("value").Value),
            EmailProperties = x.Elements("emailSettings").Select(y => new EmailProperties
            {
                SubjectName = y.Attribute("subjectName").Value,
                AttachmentName = y.Attribute("attachmentName").Value,
                SenderAddress = y.Attribute("senderAddress").Value,
                RecipientAddresses = y.Elements("recipients").Elements("address").Select(z => z.Attribute("value").Value).ToList(),
                RecipientAddressesBcc = y.Elements("recipientsBcc").Elements("address").Select(z => z.Attribute("value").Value).ToList(),
                RecipientAddressesCC = y.Elements("recipientsCC").Elements("address").Select(z => z.Attribute("value").Value).ToList()
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();

    return query;
}
```

And these are the JobConfiguration and EMailProperties classes:

```
public class JobConfiguration
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string StoredProcedure { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<string, string> ProcedureParameters { get; set; }
    public EMailProperties EMailProperties { get; set; }
}

public class EmailProperties
{
    public string SenderAddress { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Recipients { get; set; }
    public IList<string> RecipientsBcc { get; set; }
    public IList<string> RecipientsCC { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you have a choice whether you use xml or json I would pick up json.net and deserialize it as json without any additional parsers into an object. It'd be a two-liner then ;-]

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to put a disclaimer on this. My answer isn't necessarily a better way to handle this particular use case. You seem to have the simplest thing that works as far as your XML schema goes. So, take this with a grain of salt and discuss the pros/cons of each with your colleagues.

> ```
> public class EmailProperties
> {
>     public string SenderAddress { get; set; }
>     public IList<string> Recipients { get; set; }
>     public IList<string> RecipientsBcc { get; set; }
>     public IList<string> RecipientsCC { get; set; }
> }
> ```

This isn't a very object oriented way to do this. What happens if someone should be both "To" *and* "Bcc"? You'd have to duplicate the email address in the data. I would introduce another class.

```
public class Recepient
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public bool To { get; set; }
    public bool Cc { get; set; }
    public bool Bcc { get; set; }
}
```

Which makes your XML look like this.

```
  <recipients>
    <recipient to="true" >
      address@address.com
    <recipient />
    <recipient cc="true">
      john.doe@domain.com
    <recipient  />
 <recipients />
```

Note that the inner and outer elements match, but the outer is plural, while the inner is singular. Also, the *value* is placed as the value of the element instead of as a property. These are all semantically the same type of thing, but they have different attributes for whether they're "To", "Cc", etc. If it's a business rule that no one can ever have more than one of these, I'd change it a bit.

```
<recipient type="to">
    John.doe@domain.com
<recipient />
```

And the corresponding change to the new class.

```
public enum RecepientType 
{
    To, 
    Cc,
    Bcc
}

public class Recepient
{
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public RecepientType Type { get; set; }
}
```

Now, rather than review your parsing code (props for using XDoc by the way, [a lot of people try to parse XML the **hard** way](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348/3198973)), I'm going to suggest you look at using serialization to do this instead. I won't get into the nitty gritty here, but look into the [System.Xml.Serialization namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Xml.Serialization(v=vs.110).aspx). It allows us to work directly with strongly typed objects and doing all that nasty parsing for us.

Answer (score 2):

If you are not forced to use `xml` then `json` might be a better solution. You wouldn't have to worry about parsing. Here'a sample:

Everything you need to do to load it into an object is:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var jobs = File.ReadAllText("jobs.json");
        var jobsService = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JobService>(jobs);
    }
}
```

For this to work you'd to define a couple of classes:

```
public class JobService
{
    public IList<Job> Jobs { get; set; }
}

public class Job
{
    public IList<ProcedureParameter> ProcedureParameters { get; set; }
    public EmailSettings EmailSettings { get; set; }
}

public class Recipient
{
    public IList<string> Addressess { get; set; }
}

public class ProcedureParameter
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class EmailSettings
{
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }
    public string AttachmentName { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Recipients { get; set; }        
}
```

Your json would then directly be *converted* into an object:

```
{
    "Jobs": [
        {
            "Name": "Report",
            "EmailSettings": {
                "SubjectName": "Subject",
                "AttachmentName": "SomeFileName1.csv",
                "Recipients": [
                    "address@address.com",
                    "address@address.com"
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

It'd also be a good idea to follow @[RubberDuck](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/103858/59161)'s naming suggestion.

Comment: Well I wasn't really looking for ways to scrap my solution entirely, I'd rather use XML for this but this is a good answer for anyone else who comes across this post.

Comment: XML can be serialized this way too. It doesn't matter much what format the data comes in, what matters is a good structure that maps well to a set of classes. Point is, you don't have to parse the XML either.